# #SQL #QUERY #ROWNUM #ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, rownum

I would like to select 3rd salary from TABLE employees. I have written QUERY as you may see below but unfortunately it gives me 0 record. Can somebody help me on this topic ? I am using Oracle DBMS :) and here is an example of my database: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7ee358/4)

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  (SELECT ROWNUM, salary 
  FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT salary 
    FROM employees
    ORDER BY salary desc)
  )
WHERE ROWNUM = 3;
```

Comment: Do you mind providing some sample input and the expected output as `formatted text`?

Comment: since we have no idea what your table structure is, what your source data contains or what result you expected to get, it's very difficult to tell you if your query is correct or not, or what to change. We cannot magically see into your database...you need to give us complete information about your scenario - thanks.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Stating the question like this is too broad, as each RDBMS counts rows differently. SQL Server even doesn't have a deterministic row count without the notion of ordering.

Comment: Also please tag which DBMS you are using specifically - e.g. Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server etc. The syntax needed for the query or the functions available to you may be different depending on that.

Comment: SELECT ROWNUM as well from your inner query

Comment: I am using Oracle DBMS :) and here is an example of my database: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7ee358/4

Comment: ok so please edit your question to tag it with oracle, and also to include some more details of the database, and the link to the fiddle _within the question_ - entries in comments are meant to be for suggestions / brief discussions, not for information directly pertaining the questions. Thanks. (Click the "edit" button just beneath the blue "sql" and "rownum" tags to start modifying the question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In standard SQL, most databases, and Oracle 12C+, you can instead use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT salary 
FROM employees
ORDER BY salary desc
OFFSET 2 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be Oracle (ROWNUM and no alias for the Derived Table). ROWNUM is calculated for the *resulting* rows, thus you can never filter for any ROWNUM greater than 1.

You need a Standard SQL ROW_NUMBER:

```
SELECT *
FROM
 ( SELECT salary
      ,row_number() over (ORDER BY salary desc) as rn 
   FROM employees
   GROUP BY salary
 ) dt
WHERE rn = 3;
```

The GROUP BY is equivalent to DISTINCT, but processed *before* the ROW_NUMBER while DISTINCT is processed *after*.

Edit:

If you want to use ROWNUM you must alias it:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  (SELECT ROWNUM as rn, salary 
  FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT salary 
    FROM employees
    ORDER BY salary desc)
  )
WHERE rn = 3;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help,. Now everything is clear. :)